# How to happen a line segment to an existing plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I search a lot on how to happen a line segment to an existing plot using mathplotlib but didn't get an answer to my situation where I don't have a x axis.

The code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

d1 = np.arange(0, 10)
d2 = np.arange(10, 20)

plt.plot(d1)
plt.plot(d2)

plt.show()
```

I got two lines but I want to happen the 1st one to the second one.

Comment: Not sure if I got your question correct, but `plot()` takes multiple arguments and if you want to shift the second line to the left or the right, you can set `plot(d2, list(range(10,20)))`  instead of zero based default values.

Comment: @mosc9575 this is correct, but in the graph I get, the lines are not connected.

Comment: Just extend the second line by the last value of the first line at position 0. Or draw a third line with the last value af the first line and the first value of the second line at the correct possition.